# Knokout: How to load lookup data first and then the main data?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

On my web page I have 4 lookup tables (position, education, etc.) and data about selected person. I'm using Knockout and all data I load asynchronously from server.

Currently in viewmodel, first of all, I call function for loading lookup tables (functions getPositions, getEducation, etc.) and then I load the main data, but from time to time some lookup data doesn't appear. My guess is that person's data loads first some lookup data.

The way how I load data

```
this.getEducation = (function () {
    getEducation(function (data) {
       this.education = data;
    },
    function (msg) {
    });
});
```

How can I load lookup data first and only then person's data?

Comment: You're gonna need to post more code than this. What about your bindings? Where is getEducation called? Why do you have two separate functions called getEducation? Is this.education an observable array, because you're probably overwriting the variable instead of setting the observable array. Need More Code.

Comment: The problem was here 'this.education = data;'. As you mentioned I overwrote the valiable instead of setting values. I've rewrited this line in the next way 
self.getEducation($.map(data, function (value) { return value; })); and it works! Thank you for your help!